# Simple TodoList Application

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a simple to-do list application from a book on Android development. When I try to run it, I get a "this application has stopped working" message. I have absolutely no clue why, except for the fact that it has something to do with a fatal error at `setContentView(R.layout.main)`. Can someone help me fix it?

```
package com.test.tadalist;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TadaList extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

        final ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
                {
                    todoItems.add(0, editText.getText().toString()); 
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    editText.setText("");
                    return true; 
                }
                return false; 
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

layout/main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android_layout_height="fill_parent">

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Entry"
    />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a lot in your layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Entry"
    />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

A stack trace would help, but I imagine it's likely because you don't have a container for your two views. Try enclosing your two views within something like a `LinearLayout`.